# Trouble preparing database query

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am writing a java function in which I am trying to build a database query but elements of the string are not being replaced.

This is my query:

```
BOOK 

Host: 
Database: AVIATION

Generation Time: May 12, 2015 at 07:32:00 AM

Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.5.7 / MySQL 5.6.10

SQL query: SHOW columns FROM BOOK 

Rows: 4


Field Type Null Key Default Extra

timestamp varchar(15) NO NULL

concept varchar(50) NO  NULL 

page varchar(5) YES  NULL 

chapter varchar(20) NO  NULL 

section varchar(20) YES NULL

course varchar(10) NO NULL

book varchar(20) YES NULL

module varchar(2) YES NULL 

comments varchar(250) YES NULL
```

java function

```
public String prepareQuery(String q) {
    String[] array = q.split("\n");
    String q2 = " ";

    q2 += "CREATE TABLE BOOK ( \n";

    for (int i = 10; i < array.length; i++) {
            q2 += array[i];
            q2 += ",\n";
    }

    q2 += "\n);";
    // Replacing double spaces to single space
    q2 = q2.replaceAll("  ", " ");
    // this part is not working as if i see output YES NULL is still there
    q2 = q2.replaceAll(" Yes NULL ,", ",");
   // changing NO to NULL and working
    q2 = q2.replaceAll("NO" , "NOT");

    return q2;

}
```

This function is replacing everything besides "yes null".

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve, use StringBuilder rather than String to append Strings as String is immutable object.

Answer (score 1):

for me is working if I replace your code with this lines:

```
public String prepareQuery(String q) {
        String[] array = q.split("\n");
        String q2 = " ";

        q2 += "CREATE TABLE BOOK ( \n";

        for (int i = 10; i < array.length; i++) {
            q2 += array[i];
            if (i == array.length - 1)
                q2 += "\n";
            else
                q2 += ",\n";
        }

        q2 += "\n);";
        // Replacing double spaces to single space
        q2 = q2.replaceAll("  ", " ");
        // this part is not working as if i see output YES NULL is still there
        q2 = q2.replaceAll(" YES NULL,", ",");
        q2 = q2.replaceAll(" YES NULL ,", ",");
       // changing NO to NULL and working
        q2 = q2.replaceAll("NO" , "NOT");

        return q2;

    }
```

Comment: but can you tell how can i remove semicolon before closing bracket ?

Comment: I edited code to fix that problem, hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: but this produces a yes null at end